# How to remove style tag with styles inside body of html document

Tags: php

I need to remove `<style>.button {color: #fff}</style>` (there can be any other unknown styles in style tag) from body `<html><head><title>Title</title><style>.button {color: #fff}</style></head><body>qwe rty zxc<style>.button {color: #fff}</style></body></html>` (example str) with php preg_replace function

my code is

```
<?php
$html = '<html><head><title>Title</title><style>.button {color: #fff}</style></head><body>qwe rty zxc<style>.button {color: #fff}</style></body></html>';
if (preg_match('|<body>(.*?)</body>|', $html, $match))
$html = $match[1];
preg_replace('|<style>(.*?)<\/style>|', '', $html);
```

But it doesn't work.
So I have 'qwe rty zxc.button {color: #fff}' in result.
Please help.

Comment: `preg_replace()` returns the modified string. You want to assign that to a variable (`$html = preg_replace(...);`). If you do that, your code [works fine](https://3v4l.org/FFS7g).

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace() function.

```
<?php
$html = '<html><head><title>Title</title><style>.button {color: #fff}</style> 
</head><body>qwe rty zxc<style>.button {color: #fff}</style></body></html>';
$string='<style>.button {color: #fff}</style>';
$html=str_replace($string,'',$html);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to parse emails, so I dont know exactly wthat styles can be in style tag inside body of html

Answer (score 0):

So it have to be $html = preg_replace('|(.*?)</style>|', '', $html);